# SQL: how to write query for the following

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table as follows:

```
FA_Name| SP_Name | ALIAS_Name
------------------------------
FA1    |   SP1    | a1
FA1    |   SP1    | a2
FA1    |   SP2    | a3
FA1    |   SP2    | a4
FA1    |   SP3    | a5
FA1    |   SP3    | a6
```

I want to retrieve only the first ALIAS_Name records of each distinct 'SP_Name' for the given FA_Name. That means, I have to fetch records as follows:

```
FA1 |   SP1   | a1
FA1 |   SP2   | a3
FA1 |   SP3   | a5
```

Please help me writing SQl query for the same. Thanks.

Comment: For that exact data you could probably get away with `SELECT FA_Name, SP_Name, MIN(ALIAS_Name) FROM Table_Name GROUP BY Fa_Name, SP_Name`.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Thats only sample data i have given. All are varchar(100) columns. it can be any data.

Answer (score 0):

i got answer for the same and is as follows:

```
WITH duplicate AS 
(
SELECT fu_area, sp_name, analysis_name, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fu_area, sp_name 
ORDER BY fu_area, sp_name, analysis_name) AS _dupe_num 
FROM temp_rrr_test_111 WHERE 1=1
)
select * FROM duplicate WHERE _dupe_num = 1
```